# AnyDesk: mouse scroll-wheel detection when connecting from Linux to MacOS?

Tags: linux, macos, remote-desktop, mousewheel

I'm using AnyDesk to connect from my Linux desktop to a remote MacOS host, and I am having problems with the scroll wheel when using programs such as Terminal and iTerm2.

When using the scroll wheel on the MacOS host (*i.e.*, when directly using the MacOS host's mouse), it properly scrolls Terminal and iTerm2 windows.

However, when connecting to the MacOS host via AnyDesk from my linux machine and using the scroll wheel from linux, AnyDesk sends the following character sequences to the Mac:

`<ESC>[A` for scrolling up;
`<ESC>[B` for scrolling down

This causes Terminal and iTerm2 to scroll through the command history and not to scroll the window contents.

If I hold down the `<Alt>` key on the linux keyboard when using the scroll wheel, then the Terminal and iTerm2 windows scroll properly on the AnyDesk-connected MacOS device.

Is there any way to get the mouse wheel to behave this way when using AnyDesk to connect from linux to MacOS, **without** having to hold down the `<Alt>` key?

I have found nothing in the AnyDesk settings which controls this behavior.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To the moderator: it took you long enough to figure out that this question is off-topic. It was originally posted 21 months ago, and you just got around to noticing its content and closing the question now (June 4, 2022). Since I solved the problem (see my Answer here that also was posted 21 months ago), there is no need to repost this in any other forum.
But in the future, I won't post questions like this here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out ...

I just have to use `imwheel` on Linux with this configuration entry added within `~/.imwheelrc`:

```
".*anydesk.*"
None,       Up,     Alt_L|Button4,   1
None,       Down,   Alt_L|Button5,   1
```

It sends the `<Alt>` key through AnyDesk along with the mousewheel commands, and as described above, that causes the scrolling to work the way I want when running Terminal and iTerm2 under MacOS.